# Add an additional layout at the end of gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist, baseadapter, layout-inflater

I created a gridview using base adapter. Now the screen will look like below

[Current Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0JXA.png)

I have to add a new layout as last item to add more like below image

[New design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoKHH.png)

Is there any way to inflate a new layout as last item and perform a different action. My adapter class is look like below

```
public class LibraryGridZipAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<MagazineHeaderModel> mHeader;
public LibraryGridZipAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MagazineHeaderModel> header)
{
    mContext    =   context;
    mHeader     =   header;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mHeader.size();
}
@Override
public MagazineHeader getItem(int position) {

    return mHeader.get(position).getMagazine_header();
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    final MagazineHeader header             =   getItem(position);
    final HeaderDetail headerDetail     =   header.getMagazine_details();
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder                  =   new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater =   (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView             =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_libraryitem_landscape,null);
        holder.coverImage       =   (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.coverimage_library);
        holder.viewButton       =   (Button)    convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_library);
        holder.title            =   (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_library);
        holder.issue            =   (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.issue_library);
        holder.size             =   (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.size_library);
        holder.comment          =   (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_library);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder                  =   (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    String coverPath    =   header.getMag_id()+"/titleimage.png";
    holder.coverImage.setImageBitmap(Functions.getBitmap(Finals.EXTRACT_PATH + coverPath));
    holder.title.setText(header.getName());
    int size=Integer.parseInt(headerDetail.getMagazine_size());
    int sizee=size/1024;
    int sizeee=sizee/1024;
    String siz=String.valueOf(sizeee);
    holder.issue.setText(siz+ "MB");
    holder.viewButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,MagazineActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Finals.INTENT_TAGS.PAGE_ORIENTATION, header.getMag_orientation());
            intent.putExtra(Finals.INTENT_TAGS.MAG_ID, header.getMag_id());
            intent.putExtra(Finals.INTENT_TAGS.PAGE_WIDTH,headerDetail.getMagazine_page_width());
            intent.putExtra(Finals.INTENT_TAGS.PAGE_HEIGHT,headerDetail.getMagazine_page_height());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
private static class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView   coverImage;
    Button      viewButton;
    TextView    title;
    TextView    issue;
    TextView    size;
    TextView    comment;
}
}
```

Comment: you have to get the last index of array list and then check the last position of ArrayList and set your last layout in the last index of adapter. and on item select check index of view in adapter if it is last index then prform your action of last view

Comment: Can you show me an example?? I tried a lot